# The hreflang tag shows an error in the check tool. Self-referenced tag and return tag link does not properly set up.?

Tags: html, blogger, hreflang

We use 'hreflang' tag for the replacement of our website language, As I have set up the 'WEBSITE . And under the head, I have used 
`<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="hi-in" />` tag,
And for my canonical tag I have set my homepage,
If I check in my homepage URL tool, I do not see any errors and if I check the URL of my website post, Let me see the error of tool Missing return link and Self-referencing,

I want to establish the contents of my website in Hindi. But I use keywords in the post in English,

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="hi-in" /> 
<link expr:herf ='data.blog.url' rel='canonical'/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The self-referencing tag is missing, Return tag link is missing,